# problems with fseek/fread

Tags: c, fread, fseek

```
    fseek(fp,pinakas[256]*y,SEEK_SET);
    fread(pinakas,sizeof (pinakas[256]),1,fp);
    for(p=0 ; p<256 ; p++)
            printf(" %d",pinakas[p]);
```

whats the problem here?because every time i print the same numbers... y is an int which changes value. in fp i open a binary file... and i take this:

-120 36 -83 -5 0 -64 121 -73 0 -64 121 -73 0 -64 121 -73 0 -64 121 -73 0 -64 121 -73 0 -64 121 -73 0 -64 121 -73 0 64 122 -73 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 16 43 9 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 18 43 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 20 18 43 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -128 122 -107 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

i take a logical address and i turn it into physical.then i have to take a 256 byte page from a binary file and store to it physical memory.the "y" here is the page number.so with fseek i try to find the specific page in the binary file and with fread to read it and store it to pinakas[256].

Comment: Where are you trying to seek in the file?

Comment: i found out that i dont change the "y"...but anyway the print is right from a binary file?

Comment: No one can see your comments if you don't use the @username notation. You should familiarize yourself on how to use this site. You should also explain what you're trying to do in your question. Right now, it just looks like a bunch of random code without any particular meaning. Whether the code is correct or not depends on what you're trying to do, and we don't know what that is. Edit your question and add more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @NikosC. i take a logical address and i turn it into physical.then i have to take a 256 byte page from a binary file and store to it physical memory.the "y" here is the page number.so with fseek i try to find the specific page in the binary file and with fread to read it and store it to pinakas[256]. as you told me the fread function reads only 1 character.

Comment: @NikosC. voitha re patrida!

Comment: You're reading *one* element (`sizeof(pinakas[256])` is `sizeof(int)` bytes) with that `fread()` call. If you think that will populate the entire array, think again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear what you are trying to do, but this is my guess anyway: you are reading blocks of data from a file, each 256 bytes in length:

```
char pinakas[256]; //this is the memory buffer for one page

int y = ...; //this is the page number
int p;

fseek(fp, 256*y, SEEK_SET);
fread(pinakas, 256, 1, fp);
for (p = 0; p < 256; p++)
    printf(" %d", pinakas[p]);
```

One error in your code is the use of `sizeof`: `sizeof(pinakas)` is `256` (the size of the array), but `sizeof(pinakas[256])`, or any other number is just `1` (the size of any element of the array).

Comment: now i take for example this as exit:
0 0 62 -64 0 0 62 -63 0 0 62 -62 0 0 62 -61 0 0 62 -60 0 0 62 -59 0 0 62 -58 0 0 62 -57 0 0 62 -56 0 0 62 -55 0 0 62 -54 0 0 62 -53 0 0 62 -52 0 0 62 -51 0 0 62 -50 0 0 62 -49 0 0 62 -48 0 0 62 -47 0 0 62 -46 0 0 62 -45 0 0 62 -44 0 0 62 -43 0 0 62 -42 0 0 62 -41 0 0 62 -40 0 0 62 -39 0 0 62 -38 0 0 62 -37 0 0 62 -36 0 0 62 -35 0 0 62 -34 0 0 62 -33 0 0 62 -32 0 0 62 -31 0 0 62 -30 0 0 62 -29 0 0 62 -28 0 0 62 -27 0 0 62 -26 0 0 62 -25 0 0 

is this ok for a binary file? shouldnt it be only with 0 and 1 ??

Comment: @user2735769: When I say _binary file_, I mean that the file does not contain text, so you should not do for example `printf("%s", pinakas)`. Of course it has only 0 and 1: bits. But they are grouped in blocks, almost always 8 bits each, those are [_bytes_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte). In your case they are signed bytes, so you get numbers between -128 and 127.